# How to use javascript to get circle on HTML canvas to move to point onmouseclick?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So if I draw a circle on HTML5 canvas, I want to make it so that the user can click somewhere in the canvas and the circle of a given radius will move gradually to the point mouseclicked on the canvas. I know jquery has the animate function, but since the canvas does not have a DOM, I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Canvas is really not well-suited for this.  If the only thing you have going on is the circle, then SVG is a better fit for this problem, since it has an actual concept of "there is a circle here" as opposed to "there are some pixels" which is all canvas has.

Comment: I know if you click a pixel that is vertical, horizontal, or 90 degree diagonal, you can do +1 on x, +1 on y, or +1 on x and y. But I am not sure if you clicked somewhere besides the criteria aforemontioned, I am not sure how you could get it to move towards teh right direction. Sure you have the concept of the circle, but what is the algorithm/means to get it to move towards that direction?

Comment: This is easily accomplished with [fabric.js](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/) ([demo](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/)) if you don't mind using additional library, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to continuously repaint the canvas in a loop. A canvas is just a bunch of pixel data. If you want something to animate you have to draw each frame.

First clear the canvas to white (or any other color). Calculate the new position for the circle. Draw it. Wait for a short amount of time. Repeat.

Comment: I know if you click a pixel that is vertical, horizontal, or 90 degree diagonal, you can do +1 on x, +1 on y, or +1 on x and y. But I am not sure if you clicked somewhere besides the criteria aforemontioned, I am not sure how you could get it to move towards teh right direction.

Comment: If the old position is `(x0,y0)` and the click is at `(x1,y1)` then the distance between the two is `D = sqrt((y1-y0)^2 + (x1 - x0)^2).`  The unit vector in the direction you want to move is `((x1-x0)/D, (y1-y0)/D)`.  Then you add it to the original position to find the new position a distance 1 in the desired direction.